# Istio zipkin address configuration problem when using Jaeger Agent as Daemonset

Tags: istio, jaeger

I have question regarding `global.tracer.zipkin.address` while deploying istio. I am using Jaeger, and have Jaeger Agents deployed in DaemonSet. As I have each Jaeger Agents (on each nodes), Jaeger Collector, and Jaeger Query, I believe global.tracer.zipkin.address should be configured as Jaeger Agent host. However, Agents are on each nodes, and I have hard time specifying the host. How should I specify it? Thanks in advance.
FYI) If I understood correctly, Jaeger Client will send the data to the Jaeger Agent via Envoy, and then to Jaeger Collector.

Answer (score 1):

According to [istio](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/integrations/jaeger/#option-2-customizable-install) documentation:

> #### Option 2: Customizable install
>
> Consult the  [Jaeger documentation](https://www.jaegertracing.io/)  to
> get started. No special changes are needed for Jaeger to work with
> Istio.
>
> Once Jaeger is installed, you will need to point Istio proxies to send
> traces to the deployment. This can be configured with  `--set values.global.tracer.zipkin.address=<jaeger-collector-address>:9411`
> at installation time. See the
> [`ProxyConfig.Tracing`](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/istio.mesh.v1alpha1/#Tracing)
> for advanced configuration such as TLS settings.

Istio documentation states to use jaeger collector address in `global.tracer.zipkin.address`.

---

As for the Jaeger agent host, according to [Jaeger](https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.20/operator/) Operator documentation:

> <9> By default, the operator assumes that agents are deployed as
> sidecars within the target pods. Specifying the strategy as
> “DaemonSet” changes that and makes the operator deploy the agent as
> DaemonSet. Note that your tracer client will probably have to override
> the “JAEGER_AGENT_HOST” environment variable to use the node’s IP.

---

> Your tracer client will then most likely need to be told where the agent is located. This is usually done by setting the environment variable  `JAEGER_AGENT_HOST`  to the value of the Kubernetes node’s IP, for example:
>
> ```
> apiVersion: apps/v1
> kind: Deployment
> metadata:
>   name: myapp
> spec:
>   selector:
>     matchLabels:
>       app: myapp
>   template:
>     metadata:
>       labels:
>         app: myapp
>     spec:
>       containers:
>       - name: myapp
>         image: acme/myapp:myversion
>         env:
>         - name: JAEGER_AGENT_HOST
>           valueFrom:
>             fieldRef:
>               fieldPath: status.hostIP
> ```